# Determine Price Formula for Derived Security

Tags: calculus, integration, brownian-motion, finance

I think I'm on the right track for this problem, and I know it's mostly financial, but I'm stuck on a tricky integral. I'm asked:

> Assume that the risk free rate is r and that the stock price follows the equation $S(t) = S_0e^{\mu t+\sigma B_t}$ where $B_t$ is a standard Brownian
>   motion and $\mu$, $S_0$, $\sigma$, are constants ($S_0 > 0$, $\sigma > 0$). Assume that K is a positive real number. Determine the formula for the price
>   of the derived security whose payoff at time T depends on the stock price S(T) in the following way:
>
> $g(S(T)) = (\text{max} \{ S(T)-K,0 \})^2 = [(S(T)-K)^+]^2$

**Work I've Done So Far**

I started by inserting this payoff into the framework for the price of a European Call Option:
$$
  C_0=e^{-rt}E[((S(T)-K)^+)^2]=e^{-rt}E[((S_0^{\mu t+ \sigma B_t^*}-
      K)^+)^2]=e^{-rt}E[((S_0^{\mu t+ \sigma \sqrt{t} z}-K)^+)^2]
$$
where $Z \sim N(0,1)$

For the expectation, I use the cumulative distribution function for a standard normal variable $\phi(x) =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^x e^{\frac{-z^2}{2}}dz$, such that:
$$
  C_0=\frac{e^{-rt}}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} ((S_0^{\mu t+ \sigma 
      \sqrt{t} z}-K)^+)^2*e^{\frac{z^2}{2}}dz \\
     =\frac{e^{-rt}}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{S_0^{\mu t+ \sigma 
      \sqrt{t} z}>K}((S_0^{\mu t+ \sigma 
      \sqrt{t} z}-K)^+)^2*e^{\frac{z^2}{2}}dz \\
     =\frac{e^{-rt}}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{\frac{ln(\frac{K}{S_0})-\mu t}{\sigma 
      \sqrt{t}}}^{\infty}((S_0^{\mu t+ \sigma 
      \sqrt{t} z}-K)^+)^2*e^{\frac{z^2}{2}}dz
$$

**Where the Problem Arises**

Here is where I get confused.

Without the square, I could separate the two integrals and put them in terms of
$$ 
  d_\pm = \frac{ln(\frac{S_0}{K})+(r \pm \frac{\sigma^2}{2})t}{\sigma \sqrt{t}}
$$
and
$$
  \phi(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{x}e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}dz
$$

But I can't do that with the square. Should I expand the square and work it that way or is there something I might be missing. Thanks!

Comment: split the integral into 2 parts to figure out the maximum, and then square it and proceed as you are suggesting

Comment: How would I split it though @gt6989b

Comment: Any advice on how to split the integral @gt6989b ?

Comment: If you had set this up correctly you would be evaluating $C_0 = e^{-rT}\int_0^\infty [(S-K)^+]^2 f(S) \, dS $ where $f(S)$ is the risk-neutral lognormal pdf.  The integral can be evaluated as $C_0 =  e^{-rT}\int_K^\infty [S^2 - 2KS + K^2] f(s) \, dS $ in a straightforward way. It could be transformed to bring in the standard normal density as you have attempted, but in rushing ahead you have made numerous mistakes in the formulation.

Answer (score 3):

The drift $\mu$ should appear nowhere in the option price.

If the stock follows GBM, $dS/S = \mu dt + \sigma dB_t$, then to price the option you replace $\mu$ with the risk-free rate $r$ and apply Ito's lemma to get $d \log S = (r - \sigma^2/2) dt + \sigma dB_t$. This SDE can be solved to obtain

$$S(T) = S_0 e^{(r- \sigma^2/2)T}e^{\sigma \sqrt{T} z}$$

where $z \sim N(0,1)$.

The correct formulation for the call option is

$$C_0 = \frac{e^{-rT}}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}[(S_0e^{(r- \sigma^2/2)T}e^{\sigma\sqrt{T}z}- K)^+]^2e^{- z^2/2} \, dz.$$

The integrand is non-zero if $S_0e^{(r- \sigma^2/2)T}e^{\sigma\sqrt{T}z}- K > 0$ which implies

$$z > -d_{-} = -\frac{\log \frac{S_0}{K} + (r - \sigma^2/2)T}{\sigma \sqrt{T}}.$$

This reduces the integral to

$$C_0 = \frac{e^{-rT}}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\int_{-d_{-}}^{\infty}[S_0e^{(r- \sigma^2/2)T}e^{\sigma\sqrt{T}z}- K]^2e^{- z^2/2} \, dz \\ = \frac{e^{-rT}}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\int_{-d_{-}}^{\infty}[X^2e^{2\sigma\sqrt{T}z}-2XKe^{\sigma\sqrt{T}z} +K^2]e^{- z^2/2} \, dz, $$

where $X = S_0e^{(r- \sigma^2/2)T}$.

Now you can proceed to compute the integral.